# Setting percent % width of FB comments via CSS or JS: not working

Tags: javascript, css, width, facebook-comments

I'm trying to set the width in percent (80%) of the Facebook code.This doesn't work!
First I tried via css but nothing has changed. It's always of default Facebook width (500px about).

```
<div id="fb-root" style="width: 80%"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="http://stackoverflow.com" num_posts="5" width="auto"></fb:comments>
```

So, I decided to use javascript and change it width when the user resizes the browser's window. So, if my width screen is 1000px, it has to be 1000px. But when I resize the browser's window to 756px, it has to change to 756px via Javascript on the width="..." of fb:comments. The error is from Firebug (Firefox 8): box[0] is undefined -> var boxwidth = box[0].getAttribute("width");.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var box = document.getElementsByTagName("fb:comments");
    var boxwidth = box[0].getAttribute("width");

    alert("start...");
    alert("width of element 'box': "+boxwidth);
    alert("...end");

    /*resolution = screen.width;
    alert("Screen width: "+resolution);*/
</script>
```

Is there a way to set dynamically the width of fb:comments? Thanks in advance.
See you, Davide.

PS. Sorry for my English mistakes, if i did some so....

Comment: this is the code.. give us the print out html..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the fb:comments css attribute apparently is [no longer supported](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/)!

The width of the fb:comments always has to be in pixels. I'm not really sure what you are looking for, but I hope this might help to get you on your way.

in your html, create a div:

```
<div id="fbcomment">
</div>
```

between your script tags, use this piece of jquery code and replace the **body** selector with the element you want to calculate the 80% off.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    width_percent = $('body').width() * 0.8;
    fbxml = '<fb:comments href="http://stackoverflow.com" num_posts="5" width="' + width_percent  + 'px"></fb:comments>';

    $('#fbcomment').append(fbxml);
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CZpx2/3

It's a nasty workaround and it has it's limitations, but it does the trick in some situations. Hope it does for you!

Comment: It doesn't work!
-------------------------------------
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $("body").ready(function(){
 
  width_percent = $("body").width() * 0.8;
  fbxml = '<fb:comments href="http://stackoverflow.com" num_posts="5" width="' + width_percent  + 'px"></fb:comments>';
 
  $('#fbcomment').append(fbxml);
 });
</script>

Comment: @Daddie Alright, my bad. I forgot to mention that you should leave the first $(document).ready(...) untouched. I rewrote the example so it's a bit more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not working. It doesn't show the facebook's comments box. What can I do? Thank you!
PS. Did you test it on your own?

Comment: @Daddie I'd love to help, but it's hard for me to tell what's wrong if you don't give me something to work with.  
Start by making sure the fb:comments are showing without using the jquery. If it didn't work, it means you didn't follow the fb:comment instructions properly -> figure out what you did wrong there.
If you did get that to work, add the jquery google api script tag in the head together with the script tags containing the jQuery code (just like you posted in your previous comment, but leaving the first $(document) unchanged) and create the additional div in your html.

Comment: @Pascalculator nice idea, but how can I make it work also on `$(window).resize(function () {` ?

Comment: @w0rldart If you're trying to make the fb:comments responsive, you should ask yourself who resizes a browser window? 1. Developers who want to check how a site renders in a particular resolution. 2. People switching from portrait to landscape mode on their tablets/smartphones. Imho it's ok to deliberately ignore developers, but what about tablets/smartphones? The simplified answer is: look for a fb:comment width that suits both portrait and landscape mode. If that answer doesn't satisfy you, you should post your question width additional info and redirect me to it. We'll figure something out

Comment: Will do @Pascalculator, just to see more opinions but thank any way. +1

Answer (score 4):

How about this (if you're using the latest Facebook comments code):

```
.fb-comments iframe, .fb-comments, .fb-comments span { width:100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

in css
you can try adding an !important:

```
fb:comments {
  width:80% !important;
}
```

and with jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {
  $('fb:comments').css('width', '100%');
})
```

Comment: Nothing has changed although I put that on the css file.
The width it's always 500px (default of Facebook!)

Answer (score 0):

Easy, i think this Question has been asked for old fb comments plugins, now u can just add `data-width` attribute with a value of `100%`, to give it the parent width.

***Step 1***

After the `body` tag put js code as discribed in [fb docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.8appId=**YOUR_APP_ID**";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Remplace YOUR_APP_ID by appID generated by facebook

***Step 2***
Inside a block tag probably a `div` tag give it a width, and put inside it:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="YOUR_URL" data-numposts="10" data-width="100%"></div>
```

Replace YOUR_URL by the your website page url, you may also change the number of post showing.